# Filter association table prolog

Tags: prolog, meta-predicate

I need to write the include_assoc / 3 predicate that filters the associative array (second argument) with the given predicate (first argument) and writes the result to the third argument. The predicate should work analogously to include / 3. The filter predicate should use a key-value pair as argument.

I can't change the table into a list before filtering.
How can i do it?

My code

```
include_assoc(_,X,_):-
    empty_assoc(X),!.
include_assoc(Filtr,Tab,Result):-
    min_assoc(Tab,Key,Value),
    del_min_assoc(Tab,_,_,Tab1),
    (call(Filtr,Key-Value) -> 
    (include_assoc(Filtr,Tab1,Result1),
    put_assoc(Key,Result1,Value,Result));
    include_assoc(Filtr,Tab1,Result1)).
```

Comment: Please share your attempt with us and we will help you get unstuck.

Comment: @Daniel Lyons  i have pasted code

Comment: What's `Wynik`?

Comment: @DanielLyons Oh sorry, i had there other names of variables in my oryginall code, but now I introduced some changes and looks like it is working

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to convert this to a list, filter the list with the predicate, and then construct a new assoc.

```
:- use_module(library(assoc)).
:- use_module(library(apply)).

filter_assoc_l(Filter, In, Out) :-
    assoc_to_list(In, List),
    include(Filter, List, OutList),
    list_to_assoc(OutList, Out).
```

You apparently cannot do this. But you still need a way to iterate all the items of the assoc without entering a failure-driven loop which will undo your bindings after each fail. `gen_assoc` will give you all the keys, but you'll either have to use `findall/3` (making it the same as converting it to a list) or you'll have to fail after each binding (undoing your work).

Another approach here is to get the list of *keys* only, and then use the removal predicate to get rid of values when they don't match the filter. First we need to get the keys and then call a helper predicate to walk the list of keys:

```
filter_assoc_unlist(Filter, In, Out) :-
    assoc_to_keys(In, Keys),
    filter_assoc_keys(Filter, In, Keys, Out).
```

Now we can retrieve the current key/value (the head of the keys list) and then call your filter predicate to check it. If it passes, we just recur; if it fails, we remove it and pass the result of removing it into the recursive step.

```
filter_assoc_keys(Filter, In, [Key|Keys], Out) :-
    min_assoc(In, Key, Value),
    (call(Filter, Key-Value) ->
        filter_assoc_keys(Filter, In, Keys, Out)
    ;
        del_assoc(Key, In, _, Next),
        filter_assoc_keys(Filter, Next, Keys, Out)
    ).
```

When we run out of keys, the input is the output:

```
filter_assoc_keys(_, Out, [], Out).
```

I don't know if this fulfills your criteria or not, but I hope it does.